# Find the convergent interval of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)!\over (n!)(2n!)}x^n$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the convergent interval of this power series and I got the absolutely convergent interval to be $(-{4\over 27},{4 \over 27})$ by applying ratio test. But how can I verify the endpoints?

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)!\over (n!)(2n)!}x^n$$

Any hints?

Sorry, I am still confused. I plugged$-{4 \over 27}$ back to the series. 
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)!\over (n!)(2n)!}x^n$$ 
$$ = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)!\over (n!)(2n)!}(-{4 \over 27})^n$$
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {n^n\over (n!)}(-{4 \over 27})^n \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)(3n-1)(3n-2)....(2n+1)\over (n!)}(-{4 \over 27})^n \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {(3n)^n\over (n!)}(-{4 \over 27})^n$$
And that is what I got. I tried to use alternating test, but I don't think
$|{(3n)^n\over (n!)}(-{4 \over 27})^n| $ is decreasing.

Comment: You should also replace $(2n!)$ by $(2n)!$.

Comment: You check the endpoints by plugging them in and analysing the resulting series. It will converge at the negative end, and diverge at the positive one.

Comment: Checking the behavior of the $x=-4/27$ case is not hard (it's an alternating series).

Comment: Thanks! I think that should be the right radius.

Comment: It actually is true that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n=\binom{3n}{n}(4/27)^n$ is decreasing. The easiest way to do this is to show that $a_{n+1}/a_n<1$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Just for your curiosity : this is the infinite Taylor expansion of $\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-27 x}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Stirling's approximation we obtain$$(3n)!\approx \sqrt{6\pi n}\cdot\left({3n\over e}\right)^{3n}\\(2n)!\approx \sqrt{4\pi n}\cdot\left({2n\over e}\right)^{2n}\\n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot\left({n\over e}\right)^{n}$$therefore by substituting we have$${(3n)!\over n!(2n)!}x^n\approx {\sqrt{6\pi n}\cdot\left({3n\over e}\right)^{3n}\over \sqrt{4\pi n}\cdot\left({2n\over e}\right)^{2n}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot\left({n\over e}\right)^{n}}x^n={\left({27\over 4}x\right)^n\over \sqrt{4\pi n}}$$and for $x={4\over 27}$ we have $$a_n\sim {1\over \sqrt{4\pi n}}$$which is divergent. Also for $x=-{4\over 27}$ we obtain $$a_n\sim {(-1)^n\over \sqrt {4\pi n}}$$which is convergent since$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over \sqrt {n}}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over \sqrt{2n}}-{1\over \sqrt{2n-1}}\\=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
{1\over \sqrt{2n}\cdot\sqrt{2n-1}\cdot(\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n})}
\\<\infty
}$$